# Can't get content of paginated page's DOMDocument - DOMXpath PHP

Tags: php, parsing, domdocument, domxpath

In my code this is always giving first page content to me. I know the page loading before the paginate parameter. How can i get the correct contents. What should i do for the correct solution?

```
for ($page=1; $page<3500; $page++) {

    $doc = new \DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile("https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730#p".$page."_popular_desc");
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
    $elements = $xpath->query('//span[@class="market_listing_item_name"]');

    $array = iterator_to_array($elements);
    $newArr = array();
    foreach ($array as $arr) {
        $newArr[] = array(
            "itemName" => $arr->textContent
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The results of the page are being brought in from AJAX after the HTML is loaded. Therefore you would need to iterate through the AJAX file not the frontend result.

Comment: Thx this is more explanatory. Is there any library for this processor?

Comment: And which way i supposed to go? Getting url and parameter via ajax and post to php DOM ? Do i need to know any specific functions or methods for this problem?

Comment: Dear friend this is the URL that is returning JSON response `https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=0&count=20&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=popular&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1`, just try to change `start` to get the next items. If you wish you can increase `count` in order to get more results

Comment: Thx for your answer i solved it by using different service as  u say